# java two final instances with reference to each other

Tags: java

I have two classes:

```
public class Group {
  private final MyObject object;

  public Group(MyObject object) {
    this.object = object;
  }
}


public class MyObject {
  public Group group;

  public MyObject () {

  }
}
```

Currently, Group has a final instance of MyObject.

And I initiate them currently like this:

```
MyObject object = new MyObject();
Group group = new Group(object);

object.group = group;
```

However this is not what I want, since the "group" variable in "MyObject" needs to be final too (for clarity of code and easier debugging).

Is there a way I can somehow do this?

```
MyObject object = new MyObject(group);
Group group = new Group(object);
```

Where the modified constructor of "MyObject" would be as such:

```
public class MyObject {
  private final Group group;

  public MyObject (Group group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you simple class design is broken. You should avoid circular dependencies in all abstraction levels (classes, packages...). If you need to refer to the group from the object you should implement some kind of service which returns you the group for a given object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can do this is in one of the constructors.  In general you want to avoid passing `this` from a constructor, but in this cases there is no alternative (except a non-final field)

```
public class Group {
  private final MyObject card;

  public Group(MyObject card) {
      this.card = card;
  }
}


public class MyObject {
  private final Group group;

  public MyObject () {
     // initialise MyObject

     // do this only after initialising MyObject
     group = new Group(this);
  }
}

// to create both at once.
MyObject obj = new MyObject(); // will have a Group inside.
```